# Error while performing aggregate functions in Spark: ArrayType cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType

Tags: dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I am creating a Spark DF from a json containing gps data. When I try to calculate the average of a column, I'm getting the following error:

```
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o470.collectToPython.
: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.spark.sql.types.ArrayType cannot be cast to org.apache.spark.sql.types.StructType
```

I don't understand this error, since I don't have an ArrayType. This is my schema:

```
root
 |-- LastUpdateData: string (nullable = true)
 |-- DataGenerated: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Delay: long (nullable = true)
 |-- GPSQuality: long (nullable = true)
 |-- Lat: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Line: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Lon: double (nullable = true)
 |-- Route: string (nullable = true)
 |-- Speed: long (nullable = true)
 |-- VehicleCode: string (nullable = true)
 |-- VehicleId: long (nullable = true)
 |-- VehicleService: string (nullable = true)
```

```
StructType(List(StructField(LastUpdateData,StringType,true),StructField(DataGenerated,StringType,true),StructField(Delay,LongType,true),StructField(GPSQuality,LongType,true),StructField(Lat,DoubleType,true),StructField(Line,StringType,true),StructField(Lon,DoubleType,true),StructField(Route,StringType,true),StructField(Speed,LongType,true),StructField(VehicleCode,StringType,true),StructField(VehicleId,LongType,true),StructField(VehicleService,StringType,true)))
```

Here is my code:

```
df.agg({"Delay": "avg"}).collect()
```

Comment: Agg accept columns, or names of columns not structs which are just dict like in python. What you need to do is df.groupby('your columns...').agg(F.avg('delay'))  . So for example, if we want  group by vehicle_id and get the avg of speed just groupby the vehicle_id and agg by the avg of speed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
from pyspark.sql import functions

#returns the average value in the Delay Column
delay_df = df.agg(functions.avg("Delay"))

#view the output
delay_df.show()
```

Comment: Thank you very much! How can I display the output? When I execute this code it doesn't give me an error, but it also doesn't display the output. When I try using show it gives me a weird output: <bound method DataFrame.show of DataFrame[avg(Delay): double]>

Comment: Changed the solution above. Make sure to add () after .show like this `delay_df.show()`